# How to retrieve table rows in MySQL using PHP and Display it with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am trying to load a database table inside MYSQL using and display it in datatable of html. But for some reasons, no data were retrieve even though I test my query in the database. Can someone help me to solve this problem? See code below:

```js
function loadAccountsList() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '../back_php_Code/pAdminList.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function(response) {
      $('#AccountList').empty();
      var cells = eval("(" + response + ")");
      alert(cells);
      for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
        $('#AccountList').append('<tr data-empid="' + cells[i].Code + '">' +
          '<td style="font-size:11px; text-align:center;">' + cells[i].name + '</td>' +
          '<td style="font-size:11px; text-align:center;">' + cells[i].typeofloan + '</td>' +
          '<td style="font-size:11px; text-align:center;">' + cells[i].bank + '</td>' +
          '<td style="font-size:11px; text-align:center;">' + cells[i].amount + '</td>' +
          '<td style="font-size:11px; text-align:center;">' + cells[i].status + '</td>' +
          '</tr>');
      }
    },
    error: function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="..\jsScripts\jsAdminList.js"></script>


<div class="card">
  <div class="card-block">
    <div class="dt-responsive table-responsive">
      <table id="alt-pg-dt" class="table table-striped table-bordered nowrap">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>CI_CODE</th>
            <th>Fullname</th>
            <th>Type of Loan</th>
            <th>Bank</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Action</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="AccountList"></tbody>
        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <th>CI_CODE</th>
            <th>Fullname</th>
            <th>Type of Loan</th>
            <th>Bank</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Action</th>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Thanks and Regards,

[image]

Comment: I see you put the ajax inside a function, how did you call that function?

Comment: @catcon , I call it sir like this . `$(document).ready(function(){
 loadAccountsList();
});`

Comment: These are steps that I would do: 1. look at the browser's console, check for any javascript error, 2. check the response code of the ajax, 3. enable PHP error report and see there is any error with PHP

Comment: @catcon did you see any error in browser console.?

Comment: Do some debugging first to narrow down where the error occurs.  Open the php file directly in your browser. Do you see the expected output?

Comment: @catcon , I saw this on my console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are mistaking in success function. You donot need to add quotes in response and assign to the cells variable

```
 success: function (response) {
        // Now your `response` is in json which which is an array of objects
        // emptying table which is fine
        $('#AccountList').empty();
        // you are using jquery so you can simply iterate through queries like this
        $(response).each(function(index, row){
          $('#AccountList').append('<tr data-empid="' + row.empID + '">'
                + '<td style="font-size:11px; text-align:center;">' + row.badgenum + '</td>'
                + '<td style="font-size:11px; text-align:center;">' + row.empName + '</td>'
                + '<td style="font-size:11px; text-align:center;">' + row.groupName + '</td>'
                + '<td style="font-size:11px; text-align:center;">' + row.email + '</td>'
                + '<td style="font-size:11px; text-align:center;">' + row.contact_no + '</td>'
                + '<td style="font-size:11px; text-align:center;">' + row.empStatus + '</td>'
            + '</tr>');

        });

    },
```

Comment: Hi Sir, Thank you for the Answer, but may I know, what is `(index,row)`?

Comment: Sorry I was busy in my stuffs, please read - https://api.jquery.com/each/, after reading this you can query me thanks, for accepting and upvoting the answer

Comment: Thank you again Sir, now I get it. :)